# Does mockito store actions when I want to test a complicated method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to mockito. It's simple and cool framework to use (It made me love testing :) ).

I'm testing a complicated method : 
   In this method, I call a service only if data change.

```
public void testMyFacadeMethod() {   
    .... 
    If (dataChanged) {
        myService.callServiceMethod();
    }
}
```

In my test method : I prepare my mocks then I change data and I call

```
verify(myService).callServiceMethod();
```

everything is Ok and my test pass.
in the same test method I recall my facadeMethod so myService.callServiceMethod must not be called (because my data doesn't change).
Test fails :

```
verify(myService).callServiceMethod();
myFacadeMethod() <== tested method
verify(myService, times(0)).callServiceMethod(); <= tell me that this method is called once
```

My question is : does mockito store the number of times that method is called until this line ? so the first call doesn't reset the counter ?

For me, the second call of verify method will only count the number of call after the first call of verify (I'm complicating life I know :p )

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Do you recommend any test ebook to learn the art of testing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mockito.reset` to reset mocks. However, it's better to change the design of your tests. You should have two separate tests, one for each case, and you should create fresh mocks before each test.

Something like this:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    // create a myService mock
}

@Test
public void testMyFacadeMethodWithDataChange() {
    // change data, call tested method
    verify(myService).callServiceMethod();
}

@Test
public void testMyFacadeMethodWithoutDataChange() {
    // no data change, call tested method
    verify(myService, times(0)).callServiceMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Mockito does not automatically reset the number of method invocations.
You can use `Mockito.reset(T)` to reset your mock.

However, you should try to avoid to use that method. It is usually not necessary if the test code is smart and consequently its presence might indicate a code smell. See
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17